# phpmailer tls error,when i try to send mail via tls,error like belowe

Tags: php, phpmailer

when i try to send mail by phpmailer,there is some error.
Like this:

> SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-m1.mydomain.com
>   250-PIPELINING
>   250-SIZE 15728640
>   250-VRFY
>   250-ETRN
>   250-STARTTLS
>   250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
>   250-8BITMIME
>   250 DSN
>   CLIENT -> SMTP: STARTTLS
>   SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
>   CLIENT -> SMTP: EHLO localhost.localdomain
>   250-PIPELINING
>   250-SIZE 15728640
>   250-VRFY
>   250-ETRN
>   250-AUTH PLAIN
>   250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
>   250-8BITMIME
>   SMTP -> ERROR: AUTH not accepted from server: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed:     Invalid authentication mechanism
>   CLIENT -> SMTP: RSET
>   SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.0.0 Ok
>   CLIENT -> SMTP: MAIL FROM:
>   SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.1.0 Ok
>   CLIENT -> SMTP: RCPT TO:
>   SMTP -> FROM SERVER:554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied
>   SMTP -> ERROR: RCPT not accepted from server: 554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied
>   CLIENT -> SMTP: quit
>   SMTP -> FROM SERVER:221 2.0.0 Bye

**And my php code like this:**

```
<?php
 require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
 $mail = new PHPMailer();
 $mail->IsSMTP();
 $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
 $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
 $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
 $mail->Host = "m1.mydomain.com";
 $mail->Port = 25;
 $mail->Username = "service@mydomain.com";
 $mail->Password = "password";
 $mail->SetFrom('service@mydomain.com', 'service');
 $mail->Subject = "Fine Design - Avise me";
 $mail->Body = "This is very interest email for you";
 $mail->AddAddress("to@domain.com","name");
 if(!$mail->Send()) {
     $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
     echo "We're sorry, however, an error has occurred. You may manually e-mail us .";
     return false;
 } else {
     echo "Thanks! Your message was successfully sent.";
     return true;
 }
 ?>
```

but i could send mail by foxmail and other client,
Did anybody could give me some suggestion?

Comment: Mail server does not accept whatever authentication method you are attempting.

Answer (score 0):

You are using tls on port 25.
That normally should not work as port 25 is normally used for smtp without ssl/tls.

Comment: There is nothing preventing you using TLS on port 25 since it will happily work with unencrypted connections too, and it's common for handling inbound mail. The same is not true of SSL, which is why you usually see it on a separate port (465), though that has been deprecated since 1998.

Answer (score 0):

Try to test it with port 25, and with port 587.
Add:

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
        'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
```

I used it and works fine without SSL.